# What would happen when facebook reaches maximum autoincrement value

Tags: facebook

I was just wondering. What would happen to facebook database where they store messages when their autoincrement column (BIGINT) reaches maximum value?

Comment: Well the issue is not specific to Facebook only, but I can imagine the same sort of issue that would occur with any system with overflows.

Comment: On a different thought, the Max limit for BIGINT is so high that under current projected growth, the universe will come to an end before this value is reached. I could be wrong, someone please correct if otherwise.

Comment: Mark Zuckerberg will be very very happy and the % of the World population with an IQ above 50 would have dropped dramatically.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Pedantically, the % of the population with an IQ above 50 is constant by definition, as IQ is defined relative to the distribution of raw scores within a particular population. Obviously, that's not true if you apply a test weighted to this year's world population to the world's population in, say, 50 years' time, but it's one of many reasons why IQ is a really weird measurement.

Comment: @IMSoP . Do you get out much? :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson You mean into the Big Blue Room? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would fall over. However it's not very likely to happen any time soon given how big a bigint is (nine quintillion two hundred twenty three quadrillion three hundred seventy two trillion thirty six billion).

Thats presuming they even use that sort of system to store messages, if they used a nosql system it wouldn't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure SQL vs NoSQL has much bearing here: either could use a fixed-width identifier, explicitly or internally, which could overflow.

Comment: That's a perfectly valid point if nosql used an explicit or internal fixed size id then it would get the same issue.

As an addendum to my post above, I got the number wrong because BIGINT goes from negative nine quintillion to positive nine quintillion. So its actually more like 18 quintillion